# Is there a way to use a variable/combo box to select a year in a date without using date picker

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am working on a calculator to track my (and my coworkers may use it) overtime at work.  We have a bunch written in excel, but I am trying to do one in access.  There is probably a simple solution, but having searched for a couple days for using a variable in a date has only given me how to use the date as a variable.  So our pay periods are defined 1/1/yyyy to 1/15/yyyy etc. Hour pay is calculated on the number of days we have in a pay period which varies every year by days off.  I have it calculating the proper number of days using VBA, but I am having difficulty getting it to use the combo box year which defaults to current year.

I have tried setting the control source to = 01/01/[cmbYearselect]

using variables, creating a string in vba and format date

Any help would be appreciated as I am going to have to use the variable in both the control sources and vba code.

Thank you

01/01/[cmbYearSelect] results in 12/30/1899 on my form

everything else has resulted in a type mismatch for the variables etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `CDate` with no year:

```
=CDate(#01/01#)
```

or:

```
=CDate("01/01")
```

to have primo of the current year.

Comment: Thank you, I will give that a shot and play with it.  How would you use it with a combobox to select the year  combo box will be a variable from 2022 to 2122 for year.

Comment: Well, I played with it, but it help me find the solution. So thank you.  As this point is seems to work as =DateValue("01/01/" & [cmbYearSelect]).  Then I am getting the proper years.  Appreciate your help.

Comment: You should avoid string handling for dates when possible. Here you could use: `=DateSerial([cmbYearSelect], 1, 1)`.

Comment: I'll try that. If I can avoid using a string. No point in making it work harder if I don't have too.